# Errors while processing: tomcat7

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, tomcat7

I get following errors when I try to install any software or reinstall tomcat7:

```
Job for tomcat7.service failed because the control process exited with
error code. See "systemctl status tomcat7.service" and "journalctl
-xe" for details. invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "start" failed. dpkg: error processing package tomcat7 (--configure): 

subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit

status 1 Errors were encountered while processing:  tomcat7 

E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried reinstalling tomcat7 by various ways like:

1.

```
dpkg -l | grep -i tomcat
```

To remove a tomcat library:

```
dpkg -P <library-name>
```

Then, I reinstalled tomcat7 using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7

/etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop

/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```

2.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove tomcat7

sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

But it didn't solve the problem and the same error keeps coming.

What should I try next?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output from the commands `systemctl status tomcat7.service` and `journalctl -xe` as it says.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a bunch of different things before installing java, jre and the jdk.

[How To Install Java on Ubuntu 12.04 with Apt-Get | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

also changed `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setclasspath.sh` to add these lines:

```
export CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
```

Then I restarted my computer.